# What is the recommended async Oracle driver for SQLAlchemy 2.0?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

We are developing an asynchronous Python-based server using SQLAlchemy 2. So far, asynchronous access to PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite work fine. However, we cannot find an async driver for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The async driver for Oracle Database is under development.  You can follow discussion at https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/6

Comment: how about now? does it support async now?

Comment: The driver supports asyncio.  See https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/258 and https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/10679